# Formating javascript source code

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

There is js file with a lot of code in unreadable format (all code in one line):
[JS file](http://newmail.walla.co.il/editor/3.1.0.1/tiny_mce.js)

Is there a tool to format to a "normal" view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer tools, integrated in most modern browsers, are capable of cleaning up the formatting. As an example, below is an animated GIF showing how you can achieve this in Microsoft Edge:

[image]

Similar functionality exists for both [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#prettyprint-javascript), and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Pretty-print_a_minified_file) as well.

There are also [online solutions](https://www.bing.com/search?q=format%20javascript&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=format%20javascript&sc=8-16&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=01B330DCEDB74487BEECAA560AC18085) if you want to copy/paste a large block of minified code.

Comment: I loved this one (best results)

Answer (score 2):

Brian Agnew's link should work fine. There's also the standalone [Polystyle](http://www.polystyle.com) which I can recommend (costs $15 though).

On a side note, it may be better for you to get the non-minified version of TinyMCE and work with that in the first place. Some minifiers not only remove line breaks, but change variables names and other code elements as well.

Comment: what is the reason for formating code like that? Does it make it more efficient?

Comment: @samuel. It makes the file sizes considerably smaller which speeds up download of large js files. @Pekka, totally separate side note, but do you use Skype much? I added you if you want to chat sometime about that feature request.

Comment: Dowload size samuel. Its all about the download size.

Comment: @Doug: Yes, certainly! I'm in the middle of a *huge* project right now and have little time left, but how about some time come january?

Comment: @Pekka, sounds great! Until then I'll catch up with you here on SO. good luck with your project!

Comment: @Doug, excellent. Cheers and speak to you later!

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript engines beautify functions. Knowing this, here is a function that can help you with your problem:

```
function beautify (code) {
  return new Function(code).toString(0)
    .replace(/^function\s*\w*\s*\(\s*\)\s*{?|;?}?$/g, "")
    .replace(/\n\s{4}/g, "\n").replace(/^\n/, "")
}
```

SpiderMonkey and Rhino can also un-beautify (minify) them if you use `function.toString(-1)` in case you ever need to do the opposite. I also have a function for that too:

```
function minify (code) {
  new Function(code).toString(-1)
    .replace(/^function\s*\w*\s*\(\s*\)\s*{?|;?}?$/g, "");
}
```

Edit: It seems you only need to do this for tinymce.js. You can [download the TinyMCE source code](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) as it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at this: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home; A Google tool.

Choose [Pretty print] under Formatting